# Is it possible to use IPv6 in LAN with router only supporting IPv4?

Tags: windows-7, router, ipv6, homegroup, ipv4

My router (Belkin N1 Vision) seem to only support IPv4. The problem is that i'm trying to get Windows 7 Homegroup going and it requires IPv6. I'm trying to connect home computer which is connected to router via cable and laptop which uses wifi.

Is there any way to work around this issue? Set up some tunneling? There must be an easy way cause otherwise Microsoft new "easy" home networking would fail on most of the home setups.

Answer (score 4):

When your computers communicate with each other in your home network, the router acts as a simple switch, and there is no need for IPv6 support (which your router doesn't have, as pointed out by ChrisF). That is because a "normal" switch (not a "managed" switch) operates on the OSI layer 2 (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model), and decides where the packets should be sent by using the physical address (MAC address) of each network card connected to the switch. 
You can test this easily by viewing your IPv6 address for two of your computers in your home network and trying to ping the other computer with

```
ping -6 [ipv6 address]
```

If the ping goes through, you have ipv6 connectivity, and the issue with the Win 7 Homegroup lies somewhere else.

Comment: this is a good way to test, thanks. it goes through one way but does not (nor ipv4) another way so i need to figure out this issue.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this page](http://bc.whirlpool.net.au/bc/hardware/?action=h_view&model_id=717) the N1 Vision doesn't support IPv6 so it wouldn't recognise any IPv6 packets coming from your PC.

Comment: I haven't upgraded to latest one yet, i'll try tonight but i doubt they have added IPv6 since it is just a minor update. And unfortunately neither OpenWRT nor DD-WRT support this router yet.

Answer (score 1):

My personal experience is that Win 7 Home group works when all computer or devices are plugged in to the router.  My Belkins N 1 Vision router has a radio for wireless that will not handle ipv6 or Home group.

Answer (score 0):

You need ISATAP tunneling. ISATAP sees the underlying IPv4 Network as a NBMA Network like a Frame-Relay or ATM for IPv6.

http://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/understanding-isatap.html

Fred